# how to archive NSURLRequest

Tags: ios, url, nsurlconnection

is it possible to archive NSURLRequest objects?

lets say user has a list of downloads and if app terminates or crashes, it will save the list to a file. When app restarts again it'll load the file and start download where it left off.

I tried:

```
NSArray *downloadList = @[urlRequests];
[downloadList writeToFile:fileDir atomically:YES];
```

and get it back out:

```
NSArray *downloadList = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fileDir];
```

but it doesn't seem to work, does anyone have solution to this kind of problem?

thanks!!

Comment: How does the array relate to the requests?

Comment: The `writeToFile` method certainly wouldn't work, but given that `NSURLRequest` conforms to `NSCoding`, I would have thought that you could archive using `[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject: downloadList toFile:fileDir];` and retrieve it when the app starts again with `downloadList = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:fileDir];`